# Блок не виден при анимации

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день!

Есть некое подобие карусели из блоков .slide_box, внутри родительского #header_box.
По интервалу первый блок уезжает влево (через отрицательный margin), а справа приезжает следующий и так по-кругу.

Вопрос вот в чем - блок, приезжающий справа не виден частично при движении, и появляется только тогда, когда полностью попадает в видимую зону родительского элемента. [картинка](http://s006.radikal.ru/i214/1407/44/cf7257777220.jpg).
Как пофиксить проблему, друзья? =(

```
<div id="header_box">
   <div class="slide_box">1
   </div>
   <div class="slide_box">2
   </div>
   <div class="slide_box">3
   </div>  
   <div class="slide_box">4
   </div>
</div>
```

**скрипт:**

```
setInterval(function(){
   slide_w = $(".slide_box").width();

   $("#header_box").find(":first-      child").clone().insertAfter($("#header_box").find(":last-child"));

   $("#header_box").find(":first-child").animate({ marginLeft: -slide_w}, 1000);

   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#header_box").find(":first-child").remove()
   }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

**цсс:**

```
#header_box{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.slide_box{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую в след. раз использовать для описания подобного примера jsfeddle. С корректным и конкретным случаем.

Кажется вы немного неправильно понимаете в чем проблема(возможно конечно я ошибаюсь так как не видел конкретного кода, который соответствует приведенной картинке), но на первой картинке 4-й блок скрывается не справа, а снизу. Потому что идет выравнивание по родительскому div из-за свойства hidden. И все что не вошло переносится на след строку.

Как это побороть!? Можно например так, оборачиваете все `slide_box` в еще один div определенной ширины - которая в вашем случае равна  4 * на ширину `slide_box` и все будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Используйте тег:

```
 z-index
```

. выведите необходимый блок на первый план.